# how to do joins in criteria in hibernate with projections

Tags: java, hibernate, join, struts2

I am tryint to join two tables and by using Projections as well

I followed the below criteria but cant get needed one

```
Class Trans
  {
        @JoinCloumn
     }@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinColumn(name="TRANS_ONE")
private Skduler skduler;

public Skduler getSkduler() {
    return scheduler;
}

public void setSkduler(Scheduler skduler) {
    this.skduler = skduler;
}
 }

 In Skduler class I have below lines.
    @Id    
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
     @Column(name = "skduler_id")
     private String skdule_id;//getter ans setters also

     @Column(name= "TRANS_ONE")
      private String TRANS_ONE;
```

I want to make a join like below

```
     select some_cloumns from Trans join skduler on Trans.TRANS_ONE= Skdler.TRANS_ONE and where conditions.
```

I am doing criteria like below.

```
   criteria = session.createCriteria(Trans.class);
   criteria.createAlias("skduler", "sch", JoinType.FULL_JOIN);

    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
       .add(Projections.property("column_name in skduler class"), "sch");
```

SQL Query that generated is

```
    select Column_names from Trans join full left outer join skduler on Trans.TRANS_ONE = Skduler.skdule_id
```

Please help how to do joins in criteria with projections as well thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need projection at all?

Comment: I just want few columns only . If I dont use projections the other relationship columns also coming and that makes lot of time to fetch.. even its lazy fetching